# DUO API Authentication with Delphi REST Client

Tags: delphi

I'm creating a Delphi REST Client to interact with the DUO API. I was able to test my authorization keys and all other parameters in Postman just fine. However, I cannot replicate the same in Delphi REST. I'm not sure if I'm doing this wrong. Below is my sample code:

```
//aside from the parameters below
//RESTClient1 baseurl is set to: https://api-sample123.duosecurity.com/
//RESTRequest1 Resource is set to this standard resource: admin/v1/users

procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      sAuthorization, nDate, sUsername, sPassword : string;
    begin
    try   

      nDate := formatdatetime('ddd, d mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss', now()) + ' +1000';   

      sAuthorization := 'Basic justasamplekeyhere123:alsoatesthmacsha1hash';
      Restclient1.Params.Add();
      RESTClient1.Params[0].Name := 'Date';
      RESTClient1.Params[0].Value := nDate;
      Restclient1.Params[0].Options := [poDoNotEncode];
      Restclient1.Params.Add();
      RESTClient1.Params[1].Name := 'Authorization';
      RESTClient1.Params[1].Value := sAuthorization;
      Restclient1.Params[1].Options := [poDoNotEncode];
      Restclient1.ContentType := 'ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED'; //application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

      RESTRequest1.Execute;  
      MEMO1.Lines.Add(RestRequest1.Response.Content);

    Except
      On E: Exception do
                begin
                   MessageDlg(E.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
                end;
    end;
```

Comment: Could you show us (maybe screen capture) how did you configure the request in Postman to see whether there's something wrong in your transformation from Postman to Delphi code? Don't forget to blank out sensitive information.

Comment: I can refer you to an example in Postman that I used. It is basically to what I have except of course for the keys involved [link](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6074515/SVYrteh7?version=latest) I am trying to follow what the DUO API [link] (https://duo.com/docs/authapi) documentation in terms of how the parameters are setup, I guessing there could be the base64 encoding within the Postman parameters.  @Peter Wolf

Comment: You can check the request URL by RestRequest1.GetFullRequestURL(), then compare with postman request url.